# Sympy solving equations with dynamically chosen variables

Tags: python, sympy

I am using `solve()` this way:

```
a = Symbol("a")
sol = solve(a + 2)
```

`sol` has the value: `[-2]`

The problem is I need to know which variable is related to the solution.

On the other hand, this code gives the variable names:

```
a = Symbol("a")
b = Symbol("b")
sol = solve(a + b)
```

`sol` has the value: `{a:-b}`

What is the best way to get the first one to result in the form `{a:-2}` or any form that contains both the variable and the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `dict=True` will force the solution to be returned using a dictionary that identifies the variable for which a solution was found:

```
>>> a = Symbol("a")
>>> solve(a + 2)
[-2]
>>> solve(a + 2, dict=True)
[{a: -2}]
```